# How to run Authentication Thread every 4 min in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a jmeter test plan below

[image: Jmeter Testplan]

I need to run the login request every 4 minutes in order to get the bearer token. I have added the login request and a flow Control action in a thread with three threads (expected to be run three times every 4 min) and a main thread to call the services. I have used property value to transfer the bearer variable to other threads.

However, the login is running 3 times when the run started and services are failing after 4 minutes as the token request is already completed.

Can some one help here to run the login service every 4 minutes for the other services to get the bearer token

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) is configured to have 1 thread (virtual user) and loop forever

   [image]
2. You can ensure that the Login Request gets executed each 4 minutes using i.e. [View Results in Table listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-listeners-part-1-basic-display-formats/)

   [image]
3. The token can be passed to the ILS Service Thread Group via [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function and read via [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function

Comment: I have tried this, but it only runs the login thread and the other thread is not picking up.